# Swap positions between three Panels

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have three panel type objects (A, B, and C), which have been dynamically generated within another panel type control.

My question is, how can I exchange panel B to the position of panel A and panel A to the position of panel B? This will be triggered by a click on a `ToolStripMenuItem`.

What I had thought, was to go through the arrangement of panels to know who exists and from there to work them, is that correct?

```
For Each obj As Control In Panel1.Controls
    MsgBox(obj.Name)
Next
```

This is the code that I use to move to right:

```
Private Sub ToolStripMenuItem1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripMenuItem1.Click

    Dim clickedPanel = DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)
    clickedPanel.Location = New Point((clickedPanel.Location.X + 120), clickedPanel.Location.Y)

End Sub
```

This is the code I use to generate objects dynamically:

```
Private Sub TileNavItem5_ElementClick(sender As Object, e As NavElementEventArgs) Handles TileNavItem5.ElementClick
    Dim pos As Int32 = cInt(TextBox38.Text)
    Dim poslabel As Int16 = cInt(TextBox42.Text)
    Dim posY As Int16 = 330
    Dim posX As Int16 = 3

    Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(0, 0)

    Dim pb As New Panel With
    {
        .Width = 120,
        .Height = 460,
        .Top = 10,
        .Left = 10,
        .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
        .BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("C:\example.bmp"),
        .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
        .ContextMenuStrip = CntxtMnuStrpSection,
        .Name = "Panel" & Val(TextBox37.Text)
    }

    AddHandler pb.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler_b

    Dim labela As New Label With {
        .AutoSize = True,
        .Location = New Point((poslabel), 12),
        .Text = "Section " & CInt(TextBox37.Text),
        .ForeColor = Color.White,
        .BackColor = Color.Transparent,
        .Font = New Font(Me.Font, FontStyle.Bold),
        .Name = "Label" & CInt(TextBox37.Text)
    }
    pb.Location = New Point(0, 0)
    pb.Location = New Point(pos, 20)

    Panel1.Controls.Add(pb)
    pb.Controls.Add(labela)

    For j = 1 To 4

        Dim pbdoors As New Panel With
        {
            .Width = 114,
            .Height = 98,
            .Top = 10,
            .Left = 10,
            .BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle,
            .BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch,
            .ContextMenuStrip = CntxtMnuStrpUnit,
            .Name = "Unit" & Val(TextBox37.Text) & j
        }

        AddHandler pbdoors.Click, AddressOf myClickHandler_doors

        pbdoors.Location = New Point(posX, posY)
        pb.Controls.Add(pbdoors)

        posY = (posY - 100)

    Next

    Panel1.AutoScrollPosition = New Point(Panel1.HorizontalScroll.Maximum, Panel1.VerticalScroll.Maximum)

    TextBox37.Text = CInt(TextBox37.Text) + 1
    TextBox38.Text = Val(TextBox38.Text) + 120
End Sub
```

Comment: A simple swap? `Dim temp = A.Location` `A.Location = B.Location` `B.Location = temp`

Comment: @djv, thank you for your answer, and is pretty simple your solution, but, in this case, how can I know the position of Panel A?, I know the position of Panel B, but A?

Comment: What's the name of Panel A?

Comment: @LarsTech, thank you for your answer, in this example is Panel A, but when I create the panels, I do this dynamically. My doubt is, if I want to swap the position for example, Panel C to B and C to B, or other example, A to B and B to A.

Comment: Give the panels a name when you create them dynamically, then you can reference them by name in the container's Control collection.

Comment: `DirectCast(DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, ToolStripMenuItem).Owner, ContextMenuStrip).SourceControl, Panel)` that's a lot of digging. Add the panels to a collection when you create them so you can reference them directly later. Like what @LarsTech said.

Comment: Use a TableLayoutPanel to arrange your Controls. Then you don't need to know who's on the Left/Right/Top/Botton of whom, you just need to move a Control to the next/previous Column/Row and move the Control that occupies that position (whatever control that is) to the selected Control's Cell. See the [GetControlFromPosition](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getcontrolfromposition) and [GetPositionFromControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.getpositionfromcontrol) methods, for example.

Comment: If you had supplied code showing how they are created, you'd probably have an answer by now *hint, hint*

Comment: @djv, I add the code to create the objects, this is inside of Panel. Thank you.

Comment: @LARC are the panels in here `For j = 1 To 4

        Dim pbdoors As New Panel With ...` ?

Comment: @djv, yes I generate four panels within the panel that has just been generated. That is, a grandfather (Panel1), a father (A, B or C) and four grandchildren.

Comment: And a one Label for each Father.

Comment: @Jimi, thank you for your answer. Please, let me ask you a few questions to clear this, in this case, You mean the goal is to add the object in a column, and just move it between columns?, hide or no hide columns?, create the columns dynamically?, is necessary to add object to the cells or can I to fill the cell whit image background? thank you :).

Comment: You can setup a TableLayoutPanel to host your Controls (Panels or whatever). Since these child controls occupy a Cell in the TLP and the TLP is well-aware which Cell that is, you can swap Controls between Cells by just specifying the new Cells of the two Control at the same time (if you need to swap A to the position of B and vice-versa, with `[TLP].SetCellPosition(A, [B.CellPosition]) [TLP].SetCellPosition(B, [A.CellPosition])`). [Like this.](https://imgur.com/vOIuEAQ). You can have as many Columns/Rows as you need and add/remove Columns/Row at run-time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to find the controls. Swapping is the easy part.

Finding controls is also easy if you use [Control.Controls.Find(String, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_ControlCollection_Find_System_String_System_Boolean_). But you must at least know the control's name.

The difficulty comes in here

```vb
' TextBox37.Text = CInt(TextBox37.Text) + 1 ' implicit conversion from int to string
TextBox37.Text = (CInt(TextBox37.Text) + 1).ToString()
```

where you must find the control by name and you have built some integer into the name. Can you keep track of how many times 1 is added to `TextBox37.Text`?

If you can, you can pass it into this function, and the swapping will be performed

```vb
Private Sub swap(index1 As Integer, index2 As Integer)
    ' build the panel names
    Dim p1Name = $"Panel{index1}"
    Dim p2Name = $"Panel{index2}"
    ' find the panels
    Dim p1 = DirectCast(Panel1.Controls.Find(p1Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
    If p1 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("index1")
    Dim p2 = DirectCast(Panel1.Controls.Find(p2Name, True).FirstOrDefault(), Panel)
    If p2 Is Nothing Then Throw New ArgumentException("index2")
    ' swap the panels
    Dim temp = p2.Location
    p2.Location = p1.Location
    p1.Location = temp
End Sub
```

`swap(1, 2)` will swap panel 1 with 2. `swap(4, 6)` will swap the panel 4 with 6. This logic is not included in your question (i.e. how many times is `TileNavItem5_ElementClick` called?), so you know better how to incorporate it. I hope it works for you.

Comment: thank you for your answer and support. The event TileNavItem runs "n" times. Whit your example, can I apply to "n" panel's?, My doubt is If I have n panels, it is possible to use your code to only move from left to right, right? Although I would only have to know the name of those I want to move, right?. Sorry for my fool questions.

Comment: @LARC of course. Which two do you want to swap? Well you can even change it to pass in two indices which are the `TextBox37` values i.e. 3 and 5, so they don't need to be next to each other in the first place

Comment: You should **never** store state in a UI control. That is the source of your troubles. You should have some variable which holds the index and TextBox37 should just display it (rename the textbox to something meaningful while you're at it). I'm not going to advise on this because it's a paradigm shift in your application but it's something you should learn for future projects.

Comment: @LARC i changed the method signature to take two indices. I assume you know the indices of the two panels to swap

Comment: Dear @djv, thank you for your answer. An apology for the delay in my response, but I was applying the code you kindly gave me to the code I had already made. Make some changes to be able to apply it, but in the end with your help I achieved the goal, I appreciate your response and your time, but especially your support.